# How to split price column by dot in sql into 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

the table of books has title, author, price. The price is like "56.23". I need to split it into 2 columns - dollars, cents.

```
select author, title , substring(price, '.') from book
```

is not working

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`

Comment: Dare we ask why? :-(

Answer (score 2):

Use the function [`FLOOR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) to get the number without its fractional part. Then subtract that from the number to get the fraction.

```
SELECT author, title, FLOOR(price) AS dollars, 100 * (price - FLOOR(price)) AS cents
FROM book
```

Comment: `(price - FLOOR(price))*100 AS cents`

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
SELECT autho, title, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(price, '.', 1) as dollars, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(price, '.', -1) as cents
FROM book
```

Example with $123.45:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(123.45, '.', 1) as dollars, SUBSTRING_INDEX(123.45, '.', -1) as cents;
+-----------+---------+
|   dollars |   cents |
|-----------+---------|
|       123 |      45 |
+-----------+---------+
1 row in set
Time: 0.002s
```

Comment: @Strawberry you are correct I rephrased it